# how to stop a function in if statement in react native?

Tags: react-native, function, if-statement, expo-calendar

I want to use if statement in a function such that **"if there is x ,don't continue function" ** "else ,continue the function"....
my code is like below,i dont know why it continue doing the function!(it create calendar)
plz help me

```
const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(
      Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT
    );
    const filterdcalender = calendars.filter((e) => e.name === "new Calendar");
    if (filterdcalender ==! undefined || filterdcalender ==! null) {
      console.log('✅ Calender already exists');
      console.log({ filterdcalender });
      return;
    } else{const defaultCalendarSource =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? await getDefaultCalendarSource()
      : { isLocalAccount: true, name: 'new Calendar' };
    //     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////new calendar
    const newCalendarID = await Calendar.createCalendarAsync({
      title: 'Title New Calendar',
      color: 'blue',
      entityType: Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT,
      sourceId: defaultCalendarSource.id,
      source: defaultCalendarSource,
      name: 'name New Calendar',
      ownerAccount: 'personal',
      accessLevel: Calendar.CalendarAccessLevel.OWNER,
    });
    console.log(`Your new calendar ID is: ${newCalendarID}`);    
  }}
```

Comment: `==!`?  sure about that?

Comment: @derpirscher I changed it to ``` !== ``` but It works in reverse (does not create calendar even if doesn't exist)

Comment: well, you are using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which will never return `null` or `undefined` You should check if, the result contains any elements instead

Comment: thank you @derpirscher how to right "contain any elements"?? you mean like the link which you send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `a ==! b` isn't doing what you probably think it does. Because semantically it's equivalent to `a == (!b)`. Use `!==` instead.

Second [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will never return `null` or `undefined`. It will always return an array (which may be empty if no value meeting the condition is found). Thus `filteredcalender !== null || fillteredcalendar !== undefined` will always be `true`

You could either check the length of the filtered array

```
const filterdcalendar = calendars.filter((e) => e.name === "new Calendar");
if (filteredcalendar.length > 0) { 
  //calendar already exists 
  return;
}
else { 
  //create new calendar 
}
```

Or you could make use of [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const filterdcalendar = calendars.find((e) => e.name === "new Calendar");
if (filteredcalendar !== undefined) { 
  //calendar already exists 
  return;
}
else { 
  //create new calendar 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the points you mentioned ... unfortunately  your code doesn't work! the output of `console.log(calendars.find((e) => e.name === "new Calendar")` is `undefined`

Comment: Then the array doesn't contain a calendar with `name === "new Calendar"`

Comment: thanks for your time... you teach me many things